# Will this integral be progressively measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Assume you have a function: $F(t,x,\omega)$: $[0,T]\times E\times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is predictable (predictable is explained below). Each of the three spaces can be viewed as 3 measure spaces of their own. $([0,T],\mathcal{B}([0,T]),\mathcal{L})$ , $(E,\mathcal{B}(E),\nu)$, we assume that $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite, and $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. We also assume that the probability space has a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$. We also assume that $E \subset \mathbb{R}$

That $F$ is predictable means that $F$ as a function of 3 variables is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$, which means that if $A\subset \mathcal{G}$, then $A\subset \mathcal{P}([0,T])\times \mathcal{P}(E)\times\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. And $\mathcal{G}$ is generated by the functions $h(t,x,\omega)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. If you keep $t$ fixed, then as a function of $(x,\omega)$ h is $\mathcal{B}(E)\times \mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.
2. If you keep $x$ and $\omega$ fixed, $h$ is left-continuous as a function of $t$.

Now assume that $F$ is predictable and that $P(\int_0^T\int_E F(t,x,\omega)^2\nu(dx)dt<\infty)=1$.

**What can we then say about the measurability as a function of $(t,\omega)$ of $K(t,\omega)=\int_E F(t,x,\omega)^2\nu(dx)$?**

What I need for an argument I am reading in a book to work(it is a stopping-time argument), is that this $K$ has to be progressively measurable. That is, if we for any $t$, restrict $K(s,\omega)$ from $[0,T]\times \Omega$ to $[0,t]\times\Omega$, then it is $\mathcal{B}([0,t])\times \mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.

I assume that it is very likely that this is the case, but I don't know how to prove it. Do you know if it is the case? How can I prove it?

PS: My goal is to show that $\int_0^t\int_EF(s,x,\omega)^2\nu(dx)ds$ is progressively measurable, is it a way to see directly that this is progressively measurable as a function of $(t,\omega)$?

Comment: any stopped progressively measurable process is again progressively measurable http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991099/proof-of-the-progressiveness-of-a-stopped-progressive-process

Comment: @William Thanks, but I do not have a stopped process, I have an integrated process?

Comment: see theorem 1: https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/preservation-of-the-local-martingale-property/; the ito integral of any predictable process wrt a local martingale will be a local martingale under mild conditions, and in particular progressively measurable (since any local martingale is progressively measurable)

Comment: But I am not working with the Itô-integral in my problem.

Comment: well then obviously it is progressively measurable -- it's a measurable function of the original process, which is progressively measurable

Comment: Do you mean that the integral with respect to $\nu(dx)$ is a measurable function, and it preserves measurability?

Comment: I mean that the integral is pathwise, I.e. given $\omega \in \Omega$, and that for each $\omega$, $F(t,x,\omega)$ is a measurable function, so therefore $\int F(t,x,\omega) \nu (dx)$ is measurable also. It's a real analysis result, has nothing to do with probability.

Comment: Is it Fubini/Tonelli you are talking about? That talks about measurability not progressive measurability?

Comment: Yes that is one way to think about it. Progressive measurability is the same as joint measurability. If you integrate a jointly measurable function with respect to one of the variables, it won't affect the joint measurability at all.

Comment: No, it is not the same, progressive meaurability is stronger than joint measurability.

Comment: Barely. It just means that for every $t$, the process is jointly measurable on $[0,t] \times \Omega$. Just apply Fubini for every $t$ and you're done. It makes no practical difference. Also you might want to cite the exact book and theorem you are looking at, because it is unclear what your question is or why you are even confused.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42162/discussion-between-william-and-user119615).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal P$ denote the predictable $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,\infty)\times\Omega$. What you have described is a function $F$ for which $(x,(t,\omega))\mapsto F(t,x,\omega)$ is $\mathcal B(E)\otimes\mathcal P$-measurable. Now just apply Fubini/Tonelli theorem to deduce that $(t,\omega)\mapsto\int_E F(t,x,\omega)^2\,\nu(dx)$ is $\mathcal P$-measurable, i.e. predictable.